# Contact subtype custom sets not loaded on webform

Tags: webform-civicrm

Since the webform CiviCRM module to 6.2.2 the option to add a custom set related to the contact sub type when selecting the contact sub type under CiviCRM webform settings.

Drupal: 9.5.2
Webform civicrm: 6.2.2
CiviCRM: 5.57.1

To Replicate:

1. Create a custom set for contact sub-type Student
2. Create a webform and enable CiviCRM.
3. Select contact sub type Student. No Custom set is loaded to add on the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a regression [bug](https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/pull/766) caused after fixing an issue related to the subtype having more than one word.

Have submitted the [PR](https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/pull/831) for the fix, can you please test and let us know if it's fixed for you?

Comment: The patch fixed the problem, but we encountered another problem related to custom sets so had to revert back to 6.2.1

Comment: I have been experiencing this error for weeks now and it is preventing us from using our webform. I am glad to have found confirmation that the cause has been discovered. Does anyone know if and/or when this might be fixed?