# webform CiviCRM integration problem with custom fields and individual sub-type

Tags: custom-fields, webform-civicrm, sub-types

We have set of custom fields assigned to an individual contact sub-type (Child Summer Camp). In CivCRM 5.45.x the custom fields are available in the CiviCRM integration section of a webform.   In CiviCRM v 5.51.x and in v 5.57.x those custom fields are no longer available!

If we change the set of custom fields that were assigned to Individual and sub-type Child Summer Camp  and re-asign them to "Individual" any sub-type then that group of custom fields becomes available in he CiviCRM section of a webform in CiviCRM v 5.51.x and in v 5.57.x

Why do custom field sets assigned to an individual sub-type not work in CiviCRM 5.57.x?
Is it a bug or a configuration issue.

We want to assign certain custom field sets to individual sub-types.

Comment: maybe this https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/pull/831#event-8379024880

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly the issue.  Also described at:  https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/43366/contact-subtype-custom-sets-not-loaded-on-webform     I see that work is being done to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a regression [bug](https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/pull/766) caused after fixing an issue related to the subtype having more than one word.

Have submitted the [PR](https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/pull/831) for the fix, can you please test and let us know if it's fixed for you?

Comment: We are using CiviCRM 5.57.1  with webform_civicrm Version: 6.2.2 and still experience this issue.  What versions should we use in order to test the fix?

Comment: You will need to apply the patch on 6.2.2

Comment: Or you can wait for a day, as a maintainer announced to release a version tomorrow